# Getting ExpandableListView's selected item from ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, expandablelistview

Hi I have a problem with getting the id of ExpandableListView's item from ContextMenu which I need to delete the entry from my database (im using content provider).

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_EDIT, Menu.NONE, "Edit");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_REMOVE, Menu.NONE, "Remove");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuItem.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_EDIT:
            editEntry(info.id);
            return true;
        case MENU_REMOVE:
            deleteEntry(info.id);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void deleteEntry(long id) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(DatabaseManager.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
}
```

The ContextMenu is showing but when i click on "Remove" nothing happens. Could you tell me what should i do?

Comment: You don't see the items deleted from the `ListView` or/and the provider? Have you trace what happens in your provider when you trigger a `delete()`? You may also want to post the delete method of your provider.

Comment: it worked fine with ListView

Comment: Oh i forgot to call notifydatasetchanged on my adapter - the item is indeed deleted but... its not the item which i clicked. When i try to delete last item from group it deletes the first item from the group. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ExpandableListView has two levels - groups and children - the "ID" is difficult to interpret directly.

You need to decompose the information from ExpandableListContextMenuInfo into a group position and child position.

With these two values you can then retrieve the selected item from the Adapter (here *this.exandableListAdapter*) you used as a data source for your ExpandableListView. The object that the Adapter's *getChild()* returns can be converted to whatever (custom) type you initially put into the Adapter:

```
ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuItem.getMenuInfo();
int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
MyItemClass item =(MyItemClass) this.expandableListAdapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos);
```

From this *item* you should easily be able to get the id in your database or whatever specific information you need.